# Adding Domain Admins Full access permissions to all files/folders on a drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions, dfs-r

I am experiencing some DFSR-related issues where I am seeing quite a few 'access denied' errors as well as having my netbackup jobs skip most folders. I have noticed that when we migrated the users to DFSR using GPO we had the default option 'Grant user exclusive rights' is selected by default and this excludes even local or domain admins. Now there is a way to take ownership and then grant the necessary permissions but I want to be able to do this on many folders without affecting the user permissions that are currently applied. I seem to recall that xcopy had a function but am not sure if this works with 2008R2 or 2012 server which are the 2 onsite DFSR servers that I am working with at the moment.

Is anyone aware of the best way to do this? Bear in mind that permissions inheritance is blocked for each user folder.

Thanks!
CJR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure the service account running netbackup is part of the Backup Operators group.  You should not need to give anyone full access to accomplish what you are trying to do.  Having said that, if you did need to give someone full access to a large number of folders, I would use the cacls and takeown commands to programmatically grant access.  Visit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx for cacls usage.  I would recommend trying it out on a small group to make sure you get the results you want since the tools are very powerful.

Comment: Thanks for the help, adding the netbackup account worked.